# Unobedient diagrams and a way to resume caption enumeration

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, diagrams, enumerate

The code at the bottom of this question yields [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSQGQ.jpg) image. Zooming this image at a relevant place shows the following.

[image: zoom]

As you can see the last three diagrams are broken (in (vi) and (vii) 2 is lower than what I want it to be and (viii) was supposed to be the vertices of a cube). I've tried creating the diagrams by explicit coordinates, but it results in the same thing, it won't work.

Another problem with this is that this is part of a larger document and the diagrams get moved to a different page due to, I assume, lack of space. I suppose this happens because the diagrams are all within \begin{figure} \end{figure}, but I need them to be so in order to get the appropriate caption.

How can I solve both these problems?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\roman{subfigure})}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{paren}{(#2}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=paren}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt}}

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{}{%
   \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node [mynode,label=above:30] (30) at (0,0) {};
    \node [mynode,below left  = of 30,label=left:2] (2)  {};
    \node [mynode,below right = of 30,label=right:5] (5) {};
    \node [mynode, below = of 30, label=right:3] (3) {};
    \node [mynode,below  = of 3,label=below:1] (1) {};

    \draw (30) -- (2) 
          (30) -- (5)
          (30) -- (3) 
           (2) -- (1)
           (3) -- (1) 
           (5) -- (1);

   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \hfil
  \subcaptionbox{}{%
   \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node [mynode,label=above:12] (12) at (0,0) {};
    \node [mynode,below left  = of 12,label=left:4] (4)  {};
    \node [mynode,below right = of 30,label=right:3] (3) {};
    \node [mynode,below left  = of 4,label=left:2] (2)  {};
    \node [below = of 12] (a) {};
    \node[below = of a] (b) {};
    \node[mynode, below of = b, label=right:1] (1) {};

    \draw (12) -- (4)
          (12) -- (3)
           (4) -- (2)
           (2) -- (1)
           (3) -- (1);

   \end{tikzpicture}
  }

  \subcaptionbox{}{
   \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node [mynode,label=above:10] (10) at (0,0) {};
    \node [mynode,below left  = of 10,label=left:2] (2)  {};
    \node [mynode,below right = of 10,label=right:5] (5) {};
    \node [mynode,below right  = of 2,label=below:1] (1)  {};

    \draw (10) -- (2)
          (10) -- (5)
           (5) -- (1)
           (2) -- (1);                   
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \hfil
  \subcaptionbox{}{
   \begin{tikzpicture}                   
    \node [mynode,label=right:16] (16) at (0,0) {};
    \node [mynode, below of = 16, label=right:8] (8) {};
    \node [mynode, below of = 8, label=right:4](4) {};
    \node [mynode, below of = 4, label=right:2] (2){};
    \node [mynode, below of =2, label=right:1](1){};

    \draw (16) -- (8)
           (8) -- (4)
           (4) -- (2)
           (2) -- (1);                   
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }

  \subcaptionbox{}{
   \begin{tikzpicture}                   
    \node [mynode,label=right:18] (18) at (0,0) {};
    \node [mynode, left of = 18, label=left:12] (12) {};
    \node [mynode, below of = 18, label=right:3](3) {};
    \node [mynode, below of = 12, label=left:2] (2){};

    \draw (18) -- (2)
          (18) -- (3)
          (12) -- (2)
          (12) -- (3);                   
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \hfil
  \subcaptionbox{}{
   \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node [mynode,label=above:12] (12) at (0,0) {};
    \node [mynode,below left  = of 12,label=left:4] (4)  {};
    \node [below of = 12] (a) {};
    \node [mynode,below right = of 12,label=right:6] (6) {};
    \node [mynode,below = of 4,label=left:2] (2)  {};
    \node [below of = a] (b) {};
    \node [mynode, below of = 6, label=right:3] (3) {};
    \node [mynode, below of = b, label=below:1](1) {};

    \draw ;                   
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }

  \subcaptionbox{}{
   \begin{tikzpicture}

       \node [mynode,label=above:12] (12) at (0,0) {};
       \node [mynode,below left  = of 12,label=left:4] (4)  {};
       \node [below of = 12] (a) {};
       \node [mynode,below right = of 12,label=right:6] (6) {};
       \node [mynode,below = of 4,label=left:2] (2)  {};
       \node [below of = a] (b) {};
       \node [mynode, below of = 6, label=right:3] (3) {};
       \node [mynode, below of = b, label=below:1](1) {};

       \draw ;                   
      \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \hfil
  \subcaptionbox{}{
   \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node [mynode,label=above:30] (30) at (0,0) {};
    \node [mynode,below left  = of 30,label=left:6] (6)  {};
    \node [mynode, below = of 30, label=right:10] (10) {};
    \node [mynode,below right = of 30,label=right:15] (15) {};
    \node [mynode,below = of 6,label=left:2] (2)  {};
    \node [mynode, below = of 10, label=right:3] (5) {};
    \node[mynode, below = of 15, label=right:5] (5) {};
    \node[mynode, below of = 3, label=below:1] (1) {};

    \draw ;                   
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I apologize if the code is too large. Please do adjust the question accordingly or tell me what to do to make it better. I can't exactly say what I should post, so I opted for posting all that I felt was remotely relevant.

Comment: What do you mean by broken. Can you elaborate? There is `continuedfloat` from caption package to continue the same float in the next page.

Comment: @HarishKumar I've clarified what I meant with broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not mix up the `below = of` (without `positioning` library) and `below = of` (with `positioning` library). It is always better to use `positioning` library and its `below/above/right/left = of` syntax (i.e. `of` should come after `=`). For details, refer to `pgfmanual` (17.5.3, page 230) at [search window of texdoc.net](http://www.texdoc.net) or run `texdoc pgfmanual` in your terminal.

Further, if your figure contains many subfigures that can not be accomodated in a single page, you can load `caption` package and use its `\ContinuedFloat` macro. You have to place the caption with (cont.) manually for all figures that go to the next page as I have done in the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\roman{subfigure})}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{paren}{(#2}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=paren}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
 \begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{}[0.48\linewidth][c]{%
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [mynode,label=above:30] (30) at (0,0) {};
    \node [mynode,below left  = of 30,label=left:2] (2)  {};
    \node [mynode,below right = of 30,label=right:5] (5) {};
    \node [mynode, below = of 30, label=right:3] (3) {};
    \node [mynode,below  = of 3,label=below:1] (1) {};

    \draw (30) -- (2)
          (30) -- (5)
          (30) -- (3)
           (2) -- (1)
           (3) -- (1)
           (5) -- (1);

   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \hfill
  \subcaptionbox{}[0.48\linewidth][c]{%
   \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node [mynode,label=above:12] (12) at (0,0) {};
    \node [mynode,below left  = of 12,label=left:4] (4)  {};
    \node [mynode,below right = of 30,label=right:3] (3) {};
    \node [mynode,below left  = of 4,label=left:2] (2)  {};
    \node [below = of 12] (a) {};
    \node[below = of a] (b) {};
    \node[mynode, below of = b, label=right:1] (1) {};

    \draw (12) -- (4)
          (12) -- (3)
           (4) -- (2)
           (2) -- (1)
           (3) -- (1);

   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \caption{Some figure}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}\ContinuedFloat
  \subcaptionbox{}[0.48\linewidth][c]{
   \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node [mynode,label=above:10] (10) at (0,0) {};
    \node [mynode,below left  = of 10,label=left:2] (2)  {};
    \node [mynode,below right = of 10,label=right:5] (5) {};
    \node [mynode,below right  = of 2,label=below:1] (1)  {};

    \draw (10) -- (2)
          (10) -- (5)
           (5) -- (1)
           (2) -- (1);
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \hfill
  \subcaptionbox{}[0.48\linewidth][c]{
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [mynode,label=right:16] (16) at (0,0) {};
    \node [mynode, below = of 16, label=right:8] (8) {};
    \node [mynode, below = of 8, label=right:4](4) {};
    \node [mynode, below = of 4, label=right:2] (2){};
    \node [mynode, below = of 2, label=right:1](1){};

    \draw (16) -- (8)
           (8) -- (4)
           (4) -- (2)
           (2) -- (1);
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  %\caption{Some figure (cont.)}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}\ContinuedFloat
  \subcaptionbox{}[0.48\linewidth][c]{
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [mynode,label=right:18] (18) at (0,0) {};
    \node [mynode, left = of 18, label=left:12] (12) {};
    \node [mynode, below = of 18, label=right:3](3) {};
    \node [mynode, below = of 12, label=left:2] (2){};

    \draw (18) -- (2)
          (18) -- (3)
          (12) -- (2)
          (12) -- (3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \hfill
  \subcaptionbox{}[0.48\linewidth][c]{
   \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node [mynode,label=above:12] (12) at (0,0) {};
    \node [mynode,below left  = of 12,label=left:4] (4)  {};
    \node [below of = 12] (a) {};
    \node [mynode,below right = of 12,label=right:6] (6) {};
    \node [mynode,below = of 4,label=left:2] (2)  {};
    \node [below = of a] (b) {};
    \node [mynode, below = of 6, label=right:3] (3) {};
    \node [mynode, below = of b, label=below:1](1) {};

   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  %\caption{Some figure (cont.)}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}\ContinuedFloat
  \subcaptionbox{}[0.48\linewidth][c]{
   \begin{tikzpicture}

       \node [mynode,label=above:12] (12) at (0,0) {};
       \node [mynode,below left  = of 12,label=left:4] (4)  {};
       \node [below = of 12] (a) {};
       \node [mynode,below right = of 12,label=right:6] (6) {};
       \node [mynode,below = of 4,label=left:2] (2)  {};
       \node [below = of a] (b) {};
       \node [mynode, below = of 6, label=right:3] (3) {};
       \node [mynode, below = of b, label=below:1](1) {};

      \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \hfill
  \subcaptionbox{}[0.48\linewidth][c]{
   \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node [mynode,label=above:30] (30) at (0,0) {};
    \node [mynode,below left  = of 30,label=left:6] (6)  {};
    \node [mynode, below = of 30, label=right:10] (10) {};
    \node [mynode,below right = of 30,label=right:15] (15) {};
    \node [mynode,below = of 6,label=left:2] (2)  {};
    \node [mynode, below = of 10, label=right:3] (3) {};
    \node[mynode, below = of 15, label=right:5] (5) {};
    \node[mynode, below = of 3, label=below:1] (1) {};
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \caption{Some figure (cont.)}
 \end{figure}
\lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

All roman caption numbers can be vertically aligned by fixing the width of `subcaptionbox`. Note the `[c`] in the options of `subcaptionbox` is for `inner pos` which is the default (still I added for reference).

Comment: Thanks. As I read your answer I googled 'Latex lipsum' to try to understand what it, then I immediately saw it's just that text in latin, ahaha. I managed to work it out. But there's one small detail I'd like to see fixed. Is it possible to have the roman numeral captions vertically aligned too?

Comment: @GitGud Happy to help. You are welcome :-)

Answer (score 5):

`below of=3` will give you a different result than `below =of 3`. You are mixing an older syntax and the newer one supported by the `positioning` library. I suggest sticking to the newer one, as that's recommended.

I tried to correct your figure but I'm not sure what it is supposed to look like.

For the last but one diagram, for example, using

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node [mynode, label=above:12] (12) at (0,0) {};
    \node [mynode, below left=of 12, label=left:4] (4)  {};
    \node [below=of 12] (a) {};
    \node [mynode, below right=of 12, label=right:6] (6) {};
    \node [mynode, below=of 4, label=left:2] (2)  {};
    \node [below=of a] (b) {};
    \node [mynode, below=of 6, label=right:3] (3) {};
    \node [mynode, below=of b, label=below:1](1) {};

    \draw ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

produces

[image: nodes]

but I've no idea if that is correct or not.

Comment: Yes, this is what I intended.